# Как узнать об успешности выполнения sql запроса на golang?

Tags: mysql, sql, golang

Как узнать об успешности выполнения sql запроса на golang? (БД-Mysql)
В таблице есть уникальный индекс по одному из полей.
Допустим, пользователь добавляет данные, а этот индекс уже есть.
Нужно как-то узнать, что запрос Insert не сработал
Как это сделать?

Comment: А что говорит документация по поводу статуса выполнения запроса?

Comment: а как в golang узнать статус выполнения запроса? Я использую этот драйвер   github.com/ziutek/mymysql/mysql

Comment: Тут https://github.com/ziutek/mymysql в примерах же есть проверки вида if err != nil { panic(err) } после запросов к базе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идиоматически в `go` ошибки возвращаются в результате выполнения функции (последним). В стандартной библиотеке `database/sql` сделано именно так. Вот пример выполнения sql запроса и проверка ошибки:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE age=?", age)
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Пакет, который вы использует может возвращать расширенную информацию об ошибках, используя свою структуру:

```
type Error struct {
    Code uint16
    Msg  []byte
}
```

Так что если нам необходимо идентифицировать тип ошибки, то можно использовать проверку типа с преобразованием:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE age=?", age)
if err != nil {
    if val, ok := err.(*mysql.Error); ok {
        log.Println(`Ошибка №%d: "%s"`, val.Code, val.Msg)
    } else {
        log.Fatal(err) //любые другие ошибки считаем фатальными
    }
}
```